# CountDownTimer continues to tick in background — How do I retrieve that count in onResume?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have an app with multiple timers; when I start one, I can see it counting down in Logcat in Eclipse.

When I hit the <kbd>Back</kbd> button, `onStop()` is called in the app but the timer continues to countdown in logcat (the `onTick()` is continuing to tick away).

What I would like is when `onResume()` is called, I want to get that timer which is still counting down and continue it. Is this possible?

Here are my buttons that start the countdown:

```
//Button1 Timer
final CountDown button1 = new CountDown(420000,1000,bButton1);
bButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button1.start();
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Set start time for calculating time elapsed if needed
        saveTime("START_TIME_BUTTON1", currentTime);
    }
});     

//Button2 Timer
final CountDown button2 = new CountDown(360000,1000,bButton2);
bButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button2.start();
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Set start time for calculating time elapsed if needed
        saveTime("START_TIME", currentTime);
    }
});
```

My `onResume()` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    //Reset the timers on appropriate buttons if there was something running
    //If nothing was running or timer finished - have button in default state

    //See if there was a button1 timer running - if not, it will be 0
    SharedPreferences start = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    long startTime = start.getLong("START_TIME_BUTTON1", 0);
    long timeElapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
    long timeRemaining = (420000 - timeElapsed);        
    if (timeRemaining == 0) {
    } else if (timeRemaining > 0) {
        final CountDown button1Timer = new CountDown(timeRemaining,1000,bButton1);
        button1Timer.start();
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            saveTime("START_TIME", currentTime);            
    } else {
    }
}
```

This actually works — the `onResume()` starts another timer right where the first one would be, and the text displays the appropriate number and continues counting down with the `onTick()` method. But now logcat shows 2 timers counting down instead of just one!

Ultimately I wouldn't want to start another timer, I just want to pick up the first timer I started where it is currently in the countdown at and have the `onTick()` display appropriately.  Is there a way to do that? Would services be what I'm looking for? Is it already a service since it continues to tick down in the background?

I'm a little confused on what would be best practice to get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onTick()` will continue being called until either the time remaining reaches 0 or you call `cancel()` on the CountDownTimer. 
So in your `onStop()` method you will need to call `cancel()` on the timer you want to stop receiving `onTick()` notifications.

Android's implementation of CountDownTimer uses a `Handler` to perform timing by queuing a `Message` to be sent to the `Handler` after each tick. Unfortunately there is no way to pause the CountDownTimer, so I believe you will need to create a new `Timer` with the appropriate values like you're doing currently.

When you're calculating the timeElapsed, you shouldn't use `System.currentTimeMillis()` because it can be changed at any time, instead you should use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the timer used for the wall clock (time and date) and so can change unpredictably, see the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).

Comment: Thanks Mort.  Appreciate the lookover of this - I'm still very new to this as you might imagine from my code.  Just trying to make this do what I want! Cheers!

Comment: Also, - very dumb question but - how do I call the .cancel(); on that timer?  If I put button1.cancel(); into the onResume method - it breaks.  Not sure how to do this...

Comment: Does your CountDown class extend CountDownTimer? If so can you post the error you get?

Comment: I've got it squared away now :)  And yes, my CountDown class extends CountDownTimer.  Thank you for your help - and the suggestion on SystemClock!